# Matching substring in the same place on two different strings?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list

I have been trying to solve one of the codingbat problem in Python.

Here is the problem definition:

> Given 2 strings, a and b, return the number of the positions where
> they contain the same length 2 substring. So "xxcaazz" and "xxbaaz"
> yields 3, since the "xx", "aa", and "az" substrings appear in the same
> place in both strings.
>
> string_match('xxcaazz', 'xxbaaz') → 3
>
> string_match('abc', 'abc') → 2
>
> string_match('abc', 'axc') → 0

Here is my code for it:

```
def string_match(a, b):
  count = 0
  for i in range(len(a)-1):
    for j in range(len(b)-1):
      if a[i:i+2] == b[j:j+2]:
        count += 1
  return count
```

The output from Above code:

[image]

I could not figure out what is wrong with my code.

Hope you can help me out. Looking forward for the response.

Comment: did you try to add prints to see what you’re comparing ?

Comment: Also, please always include the relevant output/error traceback as **text**, not as some image. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question

Answer (score 0):

This should do the work, passed all your test cases.

```
def string_match(a, b):
    found = 0
    for i in range(min([len(a), len(b)])-1):
        if a[i] == b[i] and a[i+1] == b[i+1]:
            found += 1
    return found

print(string_match('iaxxai', 'aaxxaaxx'))
```

You dont need to split the string, you only need to check if the chars at `i` and `i + 1` are equal. If you would like to check it for `n` length, you might need an inner loop. Also it works for `len(a) != len(b)`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
def string_match(a, b):

    shorter = min(len(a), len(b))
    count = 0

    for i in range(shorter-1):
        a_sub = a[i:i+2]
        b_sub = b[i:i+2]
        if a_sub == b_sub:
        count = count + 1

    return count
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

def string_match(a, b):
count = 0
for i in range(len(a)-1) and range(len(b)-1):
# for j in range(len(b)-1):
if a[i:i+2] == b[i:i+2]:
#print(f"{a[i:i+2]} and {b[j:j+2]}")
count += 1
return count

Comment: Please use the formatting possibilities to format your answer. Also, please add some explanation how and why it works and differs from the other answers given.